# Creating an oauth 1.0a signature for Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to connect to an API using an oauth 1.0a signature for Google Script. I am looking for the functions and libraries to use in the Google Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#make_requests_to_services_with_oauth), APIs that act on behalf of a user usually require authorization, often using the [OAuth protocol](http://oauth.net/). Apps Script doesn't provide built-in support for the protocol, but there are open source libraries you can use to perform the OAuth flow and send the credentials with your requests.

Check this [OAuth1 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1) which is compatible with OAuth 1.0 and 1.0a.

> OAuth1 for Apps Script is a library for Google Apps Script that provides the ability to create and authorize OAuth1 tokens. This library uses Apps Script's new [StateTokenBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder) and `/usercallback` endpoint to handle the redirects.
>
> **Note: OAuth1 for Google APIs is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth) and scheduled to be shut down on April 20, 2015. For accessing Google APIs, use the [Apps Script OAuth2 library instead](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2).**